External Credentials not found for basic auth
I am trying to use named credentials to authenticate to an external API.  After creating named credentials and external credentials, I tried running below code. It works fine when I put directly username and password for credentials, But when I try to use the External credentials, they do not work and throws error. I don't understand why it doesnt take external credentials here. I have added permission sets to external credentials.
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:NamedCredentials_Name');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
String username = '{!$Credential.External_Credential.name}'; // do not work
String password = '{!$Credential.External_Credential.transactionKey}'; //do not work
//String username = 'xyx'; // works fine
//String password = 'abc'; // works fine
String credentials = username + ':' + password; 
String encodedCredentials = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(credentials));
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + encodedCredentials);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

System.debug(res.getBody());

I have selected  "Allow Formulas in HTTP Header" inside Named Credentials.


Make sure that Named Credential is correctly configured to use the External Credential.
Also, the permission sets assigned to the External Credential include all necessary permissions for accessing the required objects and fields.
When using Named Credentials, you don’t need to manually handle the username and password in your Apex code. Instead, Salesforce handles the authentication for you.
Review the debug logs to see if there are any specific error messages that can provide more insight into why the authentication is failing.


Found a solution. It's best to add custom header under external credentials for basic auth. I followed this article. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_custom_headers_basic_auth.htm&type=5

Found a solution. It's best to add custom header under external credentials for basic auth. I followed this article and was able to make it work
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_custom_headers_basic_auth.htm&type=5

Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.
